# this.students.splice(index,1) is not changing in the UI [Angular]

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, filter, splice

I am trying to delete a student object I have in a students array in my parent component. The student gets deleted by passing their name to the method. However, the view does not get updated. Here is my code for the delete method using `splice`

```
 deleteStudent(name: string) {
    for (var x = 0; x < this.students.length; x++) {
      if (this.students[x].name === name) {
        this.students.splice(x, 1);
        this.students = [...this.students];
        console.log(x);
        return;
      }
    }}
```

Here is the full code for the parent class:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { student } from "../../student";

@Component({
  selector: "app-students",
  templateUrl: "./students.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./students.component.css"]
})
export class StudentsComponent implements OnInit {
  students: student[] = [
    { name: "Marwa", level: "undergrad" },
    { name: "Heba", level: "undergrad" },
    { name: "Amal", level: "postgrad" }
  ];

  txt = "";
  toBeDeleted: student;

  public undergradsList = this.undergrads();
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.undergrads();
    console.log(this.undergrads);
  }
  undergrads() {
    var Arrayres = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < this.students.length; i++) {
      if (this.students[i].level === "undergrad") {
        Arrayres.push(this.students[i].name);
      }
    }
    console.log(Arrayres);
    return Arrayres;
  }
  deleteStudent(name: string) {
    for (var x = 0; x < this.students.length; x++) {
      if (this.students[x].name === name) {
        this.students.splice(x, 1);
        this.students = [...this.students];
        this.undergradsList = this.undergrads();
        console.log(x);
        return;
      }
    }
    // const studentIndex = this.students.findIndex(e => e.name === name);

    console.log("hi delte");
  }
}
```

Here is the code for the parent's HTML component:

```
<h1>{{ txt }}</h1>
<app-under-grads
  (childEvent)="txt = $event"
  [studentList]="undergradsList"
  (studentDeletion)="deleteStudent($event)"
>
</app-under-grads>
```

Here is the code for my child component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, EventEmitter, Output } from "@angular/core";
import { student } from "../../student";

@Component({
  selector: "app-under-grads",
  templateUrl: "./under-grads.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./under-grads.component.css"]
})
export class UnderGradsComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() public studentList;
  @Output() public childEvent = new EventEmitter();

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.studentList);
  }

  sendInfo() {
    this.childEvent.emit("Hello I am sending this to the parent");
  }

  @Output() public studentDeletion = new EventEmitter<string>();
  delete(name: string) {
    //  console.log("delete it");
    this.studentDeletion.emit(name);
    console.log(name);
  }
}
```

Here is the HTML of my child component which is being rendered on the screen. studentList is an array of strings of names

```
<h2>UnderGrads</h2>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let x of studentList">
      {{ x }} <button (click)="delete(x)">X</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I just tried this code and it worked for me ... but seems like more lines of code than what you'd need for this. (I see that some have already suggested alternatives as answers below.) I have a stackblitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-moelmv

Comment: Quick programming note: if you're removing items from the thing you're iterating over, _start at the end, not the start_ because removing items from the back as you move to the front does not modify the parts you've yet to handle. Running front to back **will** absolutely ruin everything. So with that said: splice already modifies the original array. Why are you recreating it based on itself? That `this.students = [... this.students]` makes no sense, the array has already been reduced by `.splice`.

Comment: x is the whole object and you are comparing it to the name.

Comment: @DeborahK I have added my HTML file. Can you please tell me if I am doing something wrong in the HTML causing the problem?

Comment: delete(x.name) in the HTML will fix the issue

Comment: Yes. You are referencing the wrong objects. I updated my stackblitz with a corrected version of your HTML: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-moelmv

Comment: But you should compare the whole object, not just the name.

Comment: Here is an updated stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3nhmkw?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that `undergradsList` is the same as `students`

So in your **deleteStudent** function

it should be like this

```
 deleteStudent(name: string) {
    for (var x = 0; x < this.students.length; x++) {
      if (this.students[x].name === name) {
        this.students.splice(x, 1);
        this.undergradsList = [...this.students];
        console.log(x);
        return;
      }
    }}
```

Answer (score 1):

You mutate the array and then assign a new array over the top. Mutation is bad M'kay!

I use a filter for these kind of deletes

```
this.students = this.students.filter(s => student !== s);
```

You are comparing name to the full student object. Here is a fixed StackBlitz.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3nhmkw?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: I am not comparing a name to a full object. I have updated my question again

Answer (score 0):

This is not an issue with your component code. You need to update the html where you are iterating the array.

Just use `trackBy` with your ngFor.

```
    <tr *ngFor="let hero of heroes; trackBy: trackHero" >
 <td>{{hero.name}}</td>
 </tr>


trackHero(index, hero) { 
console.log(hero); 
return hero ? hero.id : undefined;
 }
```

In trackHero, you need to return an attribute which is unique in your object.